# How many different orders can we make if we have to choose at least 6 pieces of pork, at least 5 pieces of beef and zero pieces of lamb or goat?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

i would like some help to this question.

Α butcher shop has 4 varieties of meat (pork,beef,lamb,goat).

How many different orders can we  make if we have to choose 14 pieces, with at least 6 pieces of pork, at least 5 pieces of beef and zero pieces of lamb or goat?

The last part is a bit weird for me.. that means that we don't have to choose any piece of lamb and goat or we have to examine each case that we can choose from (pork, beef, lamb)  and (pork, beef, goat).

Comment: It means you don't have to pick lamb or goat but you are permitted to do so. So 6 pieces of pork, 5 pieces of beef, 3 pieces of lamb and no goat would be one possible option

Answer (score 1):

We are forced to choose 6 pieces of pork and 5 pieces of beef--no choices involved. This leaves exactly $14-6-5=3$ choices remaining. Each of these choices must be from one of only four options: additional pork, additional beef, or lamb, or goat.

So we have $4$ options for each of the $3$ remaining choices. Denote by $p$, $b$, $l$, and $g$ the number of additional pieces of pork, beef, lamb, and goat chosen to fill these $3$ slots.

We must have $p+b+l+g=3$. One way to visualize this space of choices is to consider the number of ways to order $3$ objects $*$, $*$, $*$ (representing the $3$ chosen pieces of meat), and $3$ "dividers" $\big|$ , $\big|$ , $\big|$ , where the dividers separate the $4$ different types of meat. Visually:

$$ p(*) \; \big| \;  b(*) \; \big| \; l(*) \; \big| \; g(*)$$

For example, if we choose $1$ more piece of beef and $2$ pieces of goat, then our sequence of symbols would be:

$$ \big| \;  * \; \big| \;  \; \big| **$$

Each choice of $3$ pieces of meat from the $4$ types is in one-to-one correspondence with a sequence of 3 objects $*$ and 3 dividers $\big|$. We can count these sequences using combinations: we have $6$ "blanks" and need to select $3$ locations for the dividers, so the number of choices we have is $${6\choose{3}}=\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{3!}=20$$

So there are $20$ ways to make your final $3$ selections. This means there are $20$ ways to satisfy the requirements of the problem.

EXTENSION: We can generalize this result. The number of ways to select $k$ objects from a set of $m$ types (allowing repetition of types), is given by:

$${ \, k+m-1 \, \choose m-1}$$

The $m-1$ roughly comes from the fact that we lose one degree of freedom from the fact that the sum of the selections from each type needs to equal $k$ (if we know how many pieces of pork, beef, and lamb we have chosen, then we can immediately deduce the number of pieces of goat we have chosen). Equivalently (by Pascal):

$${ \, k+m-1 \, \choose k}$$

If you like factorials:

$$\frac{(k+m-1)!}{k!(m-1)!}=\frac{m(k+m)!}{(k+m)k!m!}$$